# Git Bash not using the source value specified in windows terminal settings

Tags: git-bash, windows-terminal

Until yesterday my settings.json for Windows Terminal has this profile for Git Bash:

```
...,
"defaultProfile": "{my_guid}",
"profiles": 
{
    "defaults": {},
    "list": 
    [
        {
            "guid": "{my_guid}",
            "hidden": false,
            "name": "Git Bash",
            "source": "Git"
        },
        ...
    ]
}
...
```

which simply worked, I could use the profile and had it set as default.

Today this profile isn't recognized, Windows Terminal opens with a warning for unfound default profile and the Git Bash profile isn't in the dropdown list.

I know I can just set the profile to use the path to the Git Bash executable, but I want to know what has changed.

**Why did the profile using the source attribute worked before? Why doesn't it work anymore? Where is the piece of documentation or the release note that specifies this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why did the profile using the source attribute work before?

The `"source"` attribute indicates either a "[Dynamic Profile](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/dynamic-profiles)" or a "[JSON Fragment Extension](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/json-fragment-extensions)" for Windows Terminal.  While JSON Fragment Extensions are a fairly new feature, at the time of this answer, the Microsoft doc for the [`"source"` attribute](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/customize-settings/profile-advanced#source) still just mentions that they are used for dynamic profiles.  So apologies that my previous take on this answer assumed that this was a Dynamic Profile.

Windows Terminal includes built-in generators for dynamic profiles for WSL (any installed distribution), PowerShell Core, and Azure (although this seems to be more of a static generator).  You can find the generators in [this directory](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/tree/main/src/cascadia/TerminalSettingsModel) of the source.

JSON Fragment Extensions are used for third-party applications such as Git Bash, which recently added this as a [feature in their installer](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/issues/3183).

After you confirmed that Git Bash really was using the `"source"` attribute, I decided to try out the installer and confirm the use of the fragment extensions.  As expected, I see the same thing you do in my `settings.json` Profiles (and in the Settings UI):

```
{
    "guid": "{2ece5bfe-50ed-5f3a-ab87-5cd4baafed2b}",
    "hidden": false,
    "name": "Git Bash",
    "source": "Git"
}
```

And in `C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows Terminal\Fragments\Git`, I can see the actual extension (`git-bash.json`):

```
{
    "profiles": [
        {
          "guid": "{2ece5bfe-50ed-5f3a-ab87-5cd4baafed2b}",
           "name": "Git Bash",
           "commandline": "d:/winbin/development/Git/bin/bash.exe -i -l",
           "icon": "d:/winbin/development/Git/mingw64/share/git/git-for-windows.ico",
           "startingDirectory": "%USERPROFILE%"
        }
    ]
}
```

> Why doesn't it work anymore?

I'm honestly not quite sure.  The feature seems pretty robust, in my limited testing.  The only way I could break it was to do something pathologic, like:

- Edit the fragment itself (requiring UAC elevation), which would give a different error that you received.
- Change the `"guid"` attribute manually
- Manually deleting the fragment

Most anything else I tried was recoverable or expected:

- Uninstalling Git for Windows -- Correctly removed the fragment.  Windows Terminal was even smart enough to remove the empty parent folders on restart.
- Deleting the profile itself in `settings.json` -- Because the fragment still exists, it is recreated automatically as soon as the changes are saved.

Comment: I made sure: I went and reinstalled Git for windows (Git-2.32.0.2-64-bit), there is an option to add Git Bash to Windows Terminal, after installation the old GUID I already had in my settings.json worked as before (I guess I hadn't deleted the installation folder...)

Comment: @maja Well cool!  I guess I misunderstood how the JSON Fragment Extensions work - The documentation doesn't say that they show up with a `"source"` attribute.  I've just installed 2.32.0.2 as well, and I'm seeing what you're seeing.  I'm going to modify the answer, at least, for those that come along later.